# Find the position of all specific words

Tags: php

Below is my requirement in php code.

```
$Arr = array();
$Arr = ('JDF1','JDF2','UDF1','JDF3','UDF3');
```

I want to know the specific position for all `JDFs` and `UDFs`.

Let say `JDFs` are at `1st,2nd and 4th` position and `UDFs` are at `3rd and 5th` position. Then I should get the matched value also.

Example :

```
At 4th position I have JDF3 like that.
```

Comment: you mean JDF1 and JDF2 will give you position like JDF1 is on 1 Position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) like as

```
$Arr = ['JDF1','JDF2','UDF1','JDF3','UDF3'];
$find = 'JDF3';
$search = array_flip($Arr);
echo array_key_exists($find,$search) ? "The $find is at ".($search[$find] + 1)." position" : "We can't find $find within your table";
```

**Output:**

```
The JDF3 is at 4 position
```

Comment: Forewarning: If there are any repeated values, this solution will only take the first of the occurrences and remove the rest.

Comment: Yes that can be the case. @chrisShick. Yet OP didn't specified that case yet

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the array_keys functions with options search parameter like this.

```
$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));
```

See this for more details, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using `foreach` as

```html
<?php
    $Arr = ('JDF1','JDF2','UDF1','JDF3','UDF3');
    //initialization ;)
    $i = 0;
    
    foreach ($Arr as $key) {
        $i ++;

        echo "At position {$i} I have Key {$key}.<br />";
    }

?>
```